# Can I access ActiveMQ REST management api in c#?

Tags: c#, rest, activemq-classic, jmx, nms

I am coding with c# and activemq, using NMS 1.6.1 and ActiveMQ 5.9. I want to set a unique guid in custom property for each message when I send it, then I can delete a specific message with by its guid(NOT purge a queue, only delete one message in it).  Since I did not find any NMS api that could help, I think calling activemq jmx api is the only way.
     At first I want to use IKVM to help me, but it did not work fine. The ActiveMQ official site says that "Starting with version 5.8 we provide a REST management API for the broker. Using Jolokia JMX-HTTP bridge it's possible to access all broker metrics (like memory usage) and execute management operations (like purging queues) using REST API."
     Since I am using c# , can I access these REST management api easily ?Can these REST management api solve my problem ? Or is there any easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a consumer with a selector set to your GUID to delete the specific message.  For example:

```
ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge);
IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination, string.Format("CustomProperty = '{0}'", msgGUID));
IMessage msg = consumer.Receive();
```

This will consume the single message and remove it from the queue. I don't think the JMX REST API is necessary.

Comment: Yes, your solution is pretty smart, I should have been considering more thoroughly.